# Dynamic allocation of array in C that points to linked list

Tags: c, malloc

I have these structs and I want to initialize the PageTable and PageEntry. I want to create the shape below.

```
typedef struct PageEntry {
    unsigned int page_number;
    char mode;
    int count, R;
    struct PageEntry* next;
} PE;

typedef struct PageTable {
    int p_faults, reads, writes, disk_writes, maxFrames, curFrames;
    char* algorithm;
    struct PE **pe;
} PT;
```

[image]

I want to create a hash table, so I allocate for maxFrames PE*. My PageTable needs to have a pointer to the array and each element has to point to a linked list.
Here is my init function:

```
PT *initialize_Table(int maxFrames, char *algorithm) {
    PT *ptr = malloc(sizeof(PT));   //Aloc

    ptr->p_faults = 0;
    ptr->reads = 0;
    ptr->writes = 0;
    ptr->curFrames = 0;
    ptr->disk_writes = 0;
    ptr->maxFrames = maxFrames;
    ptr->algorithm = malloc(strlen(algorithm) + 1);
    strcpy(ptr->algorithm, algorithm);
    ptr->pe = malloc((ptr->maxFrames) * sizeof(PE*));

    return ptr;
}
```

So Ptr->pe must be an array, but it isn't.
I get this error:

[image]

What should I do ?

Comment: What error are you getting telling you it isn't an array?

Comment: @ScottHunter i did an addition to the description so you can see there

Comment: What makes you think that is an error?

Comment: @ScottHunter i get seg faults every time i try to read data from pe[1] etc and also the debugger of VS doesn't show the elements that have to maxFrames.

Comment: `malloc()` does not initialize data. Use `calloc()` to have them zero-initialized

Comment: You should start by presenting a [mre] of an actual error.  The code presented is not, itself, erroneous.  The problem is with how you are using the result.  My crystal ball is cloudy, but it seems to be showing me code assuming the `PageEntry` pointers pointing to actual `PageEntry` objects, when in fact they do not.

Comment: @tstanisl, the OP may well want to initialize the `PageEntry` pointers to null, but that's not necessarily the same as initializing to all-bits-zero.  Therefore, `calloc()` is not reliably useful for the purpose.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the code that creates a segfault. The code in `initialize_Table` allocates memory for an array of `maxFrames` pointers to data of type `PE`, but the pointers are uninitialized and you didn't allocate memory yet to store an actual data element of type `PE`. `ptr->pe` is not an array but a pointer. Arrays and pointers are nearly the same in C, and you can access `ptr->pe[i]` as long as this is part of the allocated memory.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, assuming `NULL` is all-bits-zero is a good compromise between portability, and ease of programming.

Comment: @HAL9000, under some circumstances I am prepared to write code targeting a specific C implementation, but when I am not doing that I do not recognize any "good compromises" on portability.  Those who are less deliberate than I ought at least to make their portability compromises knowingly and intentionally, so they need to know that relying on all-bits-zero pointer representations to be null pointer values in fact constitutes such a compromise.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, This is getting a little OT. I agree that when making compromises on portability it is smart to document that. But some things are considered de facto portable even when not specified in the c-standard. For instance, depending on `int` being at least 32 bits is not typically worthy of being documented. And initializing pointers with `calloc` is done so often that no platform would dare remove that support, unless it is a really weird platform not intended to run existing code. It is therefore, in my opinion, safe to consider this use of `calloc` portable.

Answer (score 1):

No, `ptr->pe` is a pointer, not an array. You allocated memory for an array and you can index `ptr->pe` as if it was an array. So `ptr->pe[i]` is valid, if `i` is within range.

The contents of this freshly `malloc`ed piece of memory are undefined. Use memset to set it to all zeros, or use `calloc` (iso `malloc`) to allocate cleared memory.

Arrays in C are second rate citizens. You can declare them , initialize them and query their size with `sizeof`, but you can't do anything else with them. For all other purposes an array variable decays (or is treated as) a pointer to the first element.

Comment: Τhank you very much. You saved me a lot of time.